# Recycler view is in black colour

Tags: android

[ScreenShot of the screen from Tab(Marshmallow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBSRc.png)

The recycler view with cardview items is showing in black. Also I cannot change background colour. But when running in android emulator it seems fine, the background is default in white color. What could i had done wrong

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mRecycleAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewss);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mRecycleAdapter = new RentalAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 75);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleAdapter);
    }
}
class RentalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RentalAdapter.RentalAdapterHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mListCount;
    int lastPosition = -1;
    RentalAdapter(Context context, int listCount) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
        mListCount = listCount;
    }
    @Override
    public RentalAdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sampcard, parent, false);
        RentalAdapter.RentalAdapterHolder rentalHolder = new RentalAdapterHolder(view);

        return rentalHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RentalAdapterHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText("sample");


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 75;
    }

    class RentalAdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mTextView;
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public RentalAdapterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        }
    }

}
```

### sampcard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ASKDNAKJDHN"
            android:id="@+id/info_text"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewss"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your custom layout file. Also check your styles.

Comment: Post R.layout.sampcard xml here

Comment: Are u set background color of layout sampcard to white? other possible change to style of application.

Comment: sampcard.xml also included. No background is set

Comment: Have you applied bg to RV?

Comment: No backgroind for RV either. Included all codes in the questions section

Comment: What is your styles of app ? You should apply white bg to your parent layout of custom layout file

Comment: Style is the default one. Also its working fine(white background) in emulator. In my personal device only this problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:background_color="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ASKDNAKJDHN"
            android:id="@+id/info_text"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this code.

Comment: Its working fine. One exception the tag is card_view:cardBackgroundColor and not card_view:background_color. It seems that my device is marshmallow so when on building the default view get loaded as black. But in emulator its nougat for it the default view is white, I think this might be the reason. Anyway thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Just add a background attribute         `android:background="@android:color/white"` to your sampcard.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ASKDNAKJDHN"
            android:id="@+id/info_text"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and got it resolved by applying Background color to the root view in XML file which in you case is Recycler view.

Add this in your Recycler View XML code :

```
android:background = "#ffffff"
```